# C++ access a derived class method using a base class pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I am trying to access the `get_workhour()` function. How do I do this?
Does polymorphism only works for overriden functions?

The `manager` class has a special function `get_workhour()` which is not present in base class `employee`. How can we call that function when both class's objects are stored in a vector of `employee` type, using polymorphism?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class employee{
    protected:
        string name;
        double pay;
    public:
        employee(){
            name="xyz";
            pay =0.0;
        }
        employee(string name,double pay) {
            this->name = name;
            this->pay = pay;
        }
        string get_name(){
            return name;
        }
        virtual double get_pay(){
            return pay;
        }
    };

    class manager:public employee{
         protected:
             int workhour;
         public:
             manager(){
                 workhour = 0;
             }
             manager(string name,double pay,int workhour):
                 employee(name,pay){
                 this->workhour = workhour;
             }
             virtual int get_workhour(){
                 return workhour;
             }
             virtual double get_pay() {
                 return pay + 100;
             }
    };
    int main()
    {
        employee emp1("vivek",1500);
        manager m1("william",1300,10);
        vector<employee*> emps;
        emps.push_back(&m1);
        emps.push_back(&emp1);
        cout<<"Name of manager is : "<<emps[0]->get_name()<<endl;
        cout<<"Pay for the manager is :"<<emps[0]->get_pay()<<endl;
        cout<<"Workhour of manager is : "<<ptr->get_workhour()<<endl;
        cout<<"Name of employee is : "<<emps[1]->get_name()<<endl;
        cout<<"Pay for the employee is : "<<emps[1]->get_pay()<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Where is ptr declared?

Comment: i have the vector that is pointer of base class type and then i am passing references to different both base and derived class objects in that vector . as emps.push_back(&m1)  , emps.push_back(&emp1) . only that get_workhour () function is giving me error i dont know why . if i comment it then rest of code works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can't and you shouldn't. If you want all `Derived` to be interacted with via `Base`'s interface, then everything you want to do to a `Derived` must be represented by `Base`'s interface.

Comment: i am sorry but i think its my typo . ptr nedds to be emps[0].

Comment: Yes indeed. That doesn't change my answer.

Comment: yes i had to add that function declaration in base class.

Answer (score 2):

In general C++ (and most object oriented languages) try to discourage downcasting (casting a base type to a derived type). If you absolutely need to you can use a [dynamic_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to cast an employee to a manager. But do this only if you are sure that your pointer actually refers to a manager. Without a cast you only have access to the base type's interface.

You can use the dynamic_cast as follows:

```
manager* m = dynamic_cast<manager*>(emps[0]);
```

Comment: i am newb to c++ . i just got wat u are trying to say but i am not able to understand this dynamic cast syntax on the referd page . can you write the syntax for me to cast it to manager class object ?

Comment: Yes but it is very much discouraged.

Comment: i am sorry but i think its my typo . ptr nedds to be emps[0].

Comment: Thank u very much it is working without adding function declaration in base class :)

Comment: Don't forget to catch std::bad_cast

Answer (score 1):

One option is to have an empty method for get_workhour() in the base class and just have the manager class override it.

Comment: i am sorry but i think its my typo . ptr nedds to be emps[0].